# Sort two level multidimensional array by value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Any way to sort the below array by the value it contains in the order field?

```
$line = array(
  0 => array(
    0 => array('order' => 3)
  ),
  1 => array(
    0 => array('order' => 1)
  ),
  2 => array(
    0 => array('order' => 2)
  ),
);
```

Required output -

```
$line = array(
    0 => array(
      0 => array('order' => 1)
    ),
    1 => array(
      0 => array('order' => 2)
    ),
    2 => array(
      0 => array('order' => 3)
    ),
  );
```

tried the below code but it does not work -

```
uasort($line, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['entity_id'] - $b['entity_id'];
  });
```

Update - The keys in all the above arrays are not-known, just written here for an eg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the below code -

```
usort($line, function($a, $b) {
    return current($a)['order'] - current($b)['order'];
});
```

Comment: Thanks, It worked, I am not able to upvote, can only accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
uasort($line, function($a, $b) {
    return array_shift($a)['order'] <=> array_shift($b)[0]['order'];
});
```

Comment: the keys keep on changing and not necessarily 0.

Comment: is it only one value (one subarray) in this parent array?

Comment: yes, the format is same, just the keys are different

Comment: Here you go. Just grab array value of subarray. Thanks php isn't c++, python or go, so changing array values inside callback scope wouldn't affect original array.

Comment: Its supported in PHP7. last PHP5 (5.6) is already passed End of Lifecycle, and not recommended to be used. You can repalce `<=>` with `>` with almost same effect.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately, I'm not able to upvote due to low reputation.